# F7 in Visual Studio 2010 - What is the opposite?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I am viewing an aspx page in Visual Studio 2010 I can hit <kbd>F7</kbd> and it then opens the codebehind.  Is there an input gesture I can use to bring me back to the aspx frontend code?

Comment: nice! i didn't know about F7. it also works with XAML and its codebehind.

Comment: Its very sweet - lots of other good shortcuts, F4 does the properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>F7</kbd> goes back and forth for me.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> toggles between design and source views on the ASPX.

Comment: Cool what editor / project are you using?  It doesn't work for me in VS2010 on a web application.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> does the reverse (but it annoyingly goes to Design view, so you have to push <kbd>F7</kbd> twice while holding <kbd>shift</kbd> to get to Source).

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f) is a listing of default keybindings.

Answer (score 2):

Well the tag is Visual Studio so I will add

what <kbd>F7</kbd> does depends on your designer settings; if you have C++ settings, <kbd>F7</kbd> builds your project(s).

You can get Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Posters from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f

Answer (score 2):

1. Set The Open Options From Tools in Visual Studio:
      Tools > Options > HTML Designer (Left Navigation) 
      Then make sure "Enable HTML designer" is Checked
      Then select "Source View" from "Start pages in".

[image]

2. Set the toggle shortcut  
     Tools > Options > Keyboard 
     Search for "View.ToggleDesigner" in "Show Commands Containing" 
     Add new shortcut to "Global" with <kbd>F7</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want <kbd>F7</kbd> do the same thing as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> just follow this http://www.mortenbock.dk/blog/2010/11/12/f7-broken-in-vs2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013 (not sure about earlier versions) it works like this:

**In Designer**

<kbd>F7</kbd> - Takes you to Code Behind

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> - Toggles between Design and Source views

**In Code Behind:**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> - Takes you to the Designer (Note: The Designer will be in  Design view. So, you will need an extra shift+7 to get to Source View)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> is so horribly slow since you have to go through the design view.

I Do: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> which is much much faster once you get used to it.

If you're like me and hate loading the sluggish design view for the front end the above hotkey + 2 inputs is better/faster than <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> - Shortcut for Sync with Active Document, i.e go to the current file in the solution finder. Then just hit up and enter and you're in the file you want!